# df.set_index returns key error python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this Pandas DataFrame and I have to convert some of the items into coordinates, (meaning they have to be floats) and it includes the indexes while trying to convert them into floats. So I tried to set the indexes to the first thing in the DataFrame but it doesn't work. I wonder if it has anything to do with the fact that it is a part of the whole DataFrame, only the section that is "Latitude" and "Longitude".

```
df = df_volc.iloc(axis = 0)[0:, 3:5]
```

`df.set_index("hello", inplace = True, drop = True)`

`df`

and I get the a really long error, but this is the last part of it:
`KeyError: '34.50'`

if I don't do the `set_index` part I get:

`Latitude    Longitude
0   34.50   131.60
1   -23.30  -67.62
2   14.50   -90.88`

I just wanna know if its possible to get rid of the indexes or set them.

Comment: [`.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.set_index) Set the DataFrame index (row labels) using one or more **existing** columns

Comment: The "hello" is supposed to be "34.50"

Answer (score 1):

The parameter you need to pass to [set_index()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) function is `keys : column label or list of column labels / arrays`. In your scenario, it seems like "hello" is not a column name.

> I just wanna know if its possible to get rid of the indexes or set them.

It is possible to replace the `0, 1, 2` index with something else, though it doesn't sound like it's necessary for your end goal:

> to convert some of the items into [...] floats

To achieve this, you could overwrite the existing values by using [astype()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):
`df['Latitude'] = df['Latitude'].astype('float')`